# How to fetch all changes with given topic from gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

We want to use topics for changes that are under development but we need to fetch them because we build from a server.
We know we can fetch a commit, and a change, but we want to fetch with the topic name for simplicity reasons.

We haven't found a way. Does somebody know how we could do this?

We have discarded the use of branches for testing developments because it brings trash to the master repository and we would have to delete them after and replicate all those deletes worldwide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [gerrit query](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-query.html) to find all open changes by a known topic:

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit query --format=JSON topic:MY-TOPIC status:open project:xxx
```

Then you can iterate over each item in the returned JSON, fetch the changes and build them with your CI.

Comment: But a topic may have more than one change. We should retrieve all the changes for a certain topic.

Thank you for your answer, but ideally we don't want to have to do direct queries.

Comment: Yes, correct, we want to know all the open changes by a topic, but if it was possible without doing a query, instead, fetch them locally.

Comment: There is no such info locally in Git. Topics are gerrit-specific so you need to fetch them from there.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but the only way to do it is through a query then?

Comment: You can always add the topic in the commit messages (or write a hook that will do it automatically). But IMHO this would be an overkill. You have to contact gerrit anyway to fetch these changes, don't you?

Comment: Yes, but we have to write a script after all, we couldn't find a hook for this.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but maybe improving bit. For CI purpose you also need refs to know patchset you need. so adding `--current-patch-set` will give that information.

You can leave also project away as it will give project information anyway. Great for multirepo projects.

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit query --format=JSON --current-patch-set topic:<TOPIC> status:open
```

Then just parse json for your needed commits.

Answer (score 1):

Gerrit has a [Changes Submitted Together](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#submitted-together) endpoint which gives you a list of all changes which will be submitted when submit is called.

This is what powers the "Submitted Together" section of the Gerrit UI.

Comment: Good to know they added this already :D Was not present back when question was posted. Thank you!